# WP_Query orderby custom field then post_date in one query

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field, meta-query

I need to order the first three posts by a custom field, and subsequent posts by `post_date` in one query - for example:

- Post 4 (`field_order`: 1)
- Post 3 (`field_order`: 2)
- Post 2 (`field_order`: 3)
- Post 1 (`field_order`: null)
- Post 0 (`field_order`: null)

`Post 1` and `Post 0` need to be ordered by `post_date`.

I can order by custom field easily enough, but when I add a post without the custom field (Post 1 & 0), it doesn't appear in the query.

Below is the query I am currently trying:

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'insights',
        'posts_per_page' => '9',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'field_order',
                'value'   => '0',
                'compare' => '>'
            )
        ),
        'orderby' => array(
            'field_order' => 'ASC',
            'post_date' => 'ASC',
        ),
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Multiple `meta_query` arguments with `OR`

You may use the `'relation' => 'OR'` argument in `meta_query` with two sets of `field_order` arguments: one with `meta_value >= '0'` and the other one with `NOT EXISTS` to generate the main query.

```
        'meta_query'     => array(
            'relation'   => 'OR',
            field_order' => array(
                'key'       => 'field_order',
                'value'     => '0',
                'compare'   => '>=',
                'type'      => 'NUMERIC'
            ),  
            'field_order_withnulls' => array(
                'key'       => 'field_order',
                'compare'   => 'NOT EXISTS',
                'type'      => 'NUMERIC'
            )
        )
```

### Proper Order by

We can use `'field_order_withnulls' => 'ASC'`, however, because of the LEFT JOIN, there will be rows with `null` `field_order` values & those will come before numeric `field_order` values in `ASC` orderby.

To fix that, we will use the `ORDER BY -field_order DESC` trick as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8174026/854549).

This will correct the ordering by inverting `DESC` to `ASC`, but keeping the rows with `null` values after the numeric values.

### Implementing the `-` (inverse) operator in `orderby`

The problem is, WordPress doesn't provide any direct way of setting the `-` (inverse) operator in `orderby`. So we will introduce a custom `WP_Query` attribute named `_inverse_order` and then use the `posts_orderby` filter to implement it.

### Sample CODE:

```
    // posts_orderby filter callback function
    // place this function in theme's functions.php file or in a custom plugin
    function wpse311227_inverse_orderby( $orderby, $query ) {
        remove_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'wpse311227_inverse_orderby', 10, 2 );
        $idx = (int) $query->get( '_inverse_order' ) - 1;
        if( $idx >= 0 ) {
            $orders = preg_split( "/(?<=ASC|DESC),[\s]*/i", $orderby );
            if( $idx < count( $orders ) ) {
                $orders[$idx] = '-' . $orders[$idx];
            }
            return implode( $orders, ', ' );
        }

        return $orderby;
    }


    // adding the posts_orderby filter to implement the custom '_inverse_order' attribute
    // this should be placed just before the WP_Query call
    add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'wpse311227_inverse_orderby', 10, 2 );
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'insights',
        'posts_per_page' => '9',
        'meta_query'     => array(
            'relation'   => 'OR',
            field_order' => array(
                'key'       => 'field_order',
                'value'     => '0',
                'compare'   => '>=',
                'type'      => 'NUMERIC'
            ),  
            'field_order_withnulls' => array(
                'key'       => 'field_order',
                'compare'   => 'NOT EXISTS',
                'type'      => 'NUMERIC'
            )
        ),
        'orderby' => array(
            'field_order_withnulls' => 'DESC',
            'post_date'             => 'ASC'
        ),
        // this custom attribute is implemented in wpse311227_inverse_orderby() function
        // to correct the ordering by placing a '-' operator
        // value of _inverse_order attribute is the position of the
        // orderby attribute to be be inversed,
        // (position starts with 1)
        // in this case, since: 'field_order_withnulls' => 'DESC'
        // is in position 1 of 'orderby' attribute array, so:
        '_inverse_order'  => 1
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

This will produce all posts with `field_order > 0` and the posts that don't have `field_order` meta data with the expected order.

> ***Note:*** You'll need to pass a non-empty `value` in `meta_query` for a `NOT EXISTS` check if the WordPress version is below 3.9. Check this [note from codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters):
>
> > Due to bug #23268, value is required for NOT EXISTS comparisons to work correctly prior to 3.9. You must supply some string for the value parameter. An empty string or NULL will NOT work. However, any other string will do the trick and will NOT show up in your SQL when using NOT EXISTS.

---

> ***Warning:*** This `WP_Query` will use two `LEFT JOIN`, which is *not very efficient*. Although, for even a few thousand posts, this is tolerable. I've tested with 15,000+ posts & the query takes approximately 0.3 second on a average. However, if you have Millions or even hundreds of thousands of posts, then you'll have to optimize the query or find a more efficient method to achieve the same result.

Comment: This query sorts values like a string. You should add `'type' => 'numeric'` to `meta_query` after `'compare' => '>'`. After that the `field_order` values will be sorted correctly but the `NULL` values will still be at the beginning.

Comment: OK @nmr, I've improved the CODE with proper ordering. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if it can be done on `WP_Query`, but this should work:

```
global $wpdb;
$sql = "SELECT p.* FROM {$wpdb->posts} p "
    . " LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} pm ON p.id=pm.post_id AND pm.meta_key='field_order' "
    . " WHERE p.post_type='insights' AND p.post_status='publish' "
        . " AND (pm.meta_value > 0 OR pm.meta_value IS NULL) "
    . " ORDER BY -pm.meta_value DESC, p.post_date ASC LIMIT 9";
$posts = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

Comment: Why downvote? In MySQL NULL values are lower non-NULL value (in ASC order, NULL go first) that's why **ORDER BY -pm.meta_value desc** is used. How do this in WP_Query (place NULL values at the end)?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but may be the OP wanted the solution with `WP_Query`. Also, the query doesn't fully replicate `WP_Query` and remove the possibility of extending using hooks.

Comment: Thanks @Fayaz, I corrected. I completely forgot about `field_order > 0`. 
I didn't assume that you downvote, I just didn't know why. Now I know.