# What's wrong with this meta query? (order by meta key, then title, doesn't work)

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, order

Here's my meta query:

```
$taxonomy_term = 1494;
$args['meta_query'] = array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        'mp_exists' => array(
            'key' => 'tdlrm_mp_'.$taxonomy_term,
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
        ),
        'mp_not_exists' => array(
            'key' => 'tdlrm_mp_'.$taxonomy_term,
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        )
    );
$args['orderby'] = array( 'meta_value_num' => 'ASC', 'title' => 'ASC' );
```

The posts where `'tdlrm_mp_'.$taxonomy` key exists get placed first as expected. Hovewer, the rest do not get ordered by their title (actually, I can't figure out what they are ordered by). What am I doing wrong?

[This answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/311227/wp-query-orderby-custom-field-then-post-date-in-one-query) doesn't help. I wrote my query according to [this manual](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#:%7E:text=%27orderby%27%C2%A0%20%3D%3E%20array(%20%27meta_value_num%27%20%3D%3E%20%27DESC%27%2C%20%27title%27%20%3D%3E%20%27ASC%27%20)%2C).

**Update**

I ran WP's MySQL query in my database and saw the postmeta table joined twice. The posts that have no tdlrm_mp_{term} meta key still have some other meta key in the resulting table and the rest of the posts get ordered by the value of that meta. (`mp_exists` adds the first postmeta table, `mp_not_exists` adds the second one, where `mp_exists` does not exist. Still some other meta key exists in the first joined table, so the posts keep getting ordered by that column).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, I had to use a 'posts_orderby' filter. I turned to Sally CJ's answers to my [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/392502/order-by-nested-named-meta-queries-with-exists-and-not-exists/392525#392525) and [another question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/392642/whats-wrong-with-this-wp-query). I thought I wouldn't need it, but I was wrong.

The reason posts do not get ordered properly is that in the MySQL query WP produces, the postmeta table get joined several times, resulting in multiple `meta_key` columns. So, in the first of the meta_key columns, where the meta key isn't `'tdlrm_mp_'.$taxonomy_term`, there still is *some other* meta key, so the posts just keep being ordered by the meta values corresponding to this column, like so:

```
/*
| wp_postmeta.meta_key | wp_postmeta.meta_value | mt1.meta_key  | mt1.meta_value |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| tdlrm_mp_1494        | 1                      | tdlrm_mp_1494 | 1              |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| tdlrm_mp_1494        | 2                      | tdlrm_mp_1494 | 2              |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| some_other_key       | X                      | NULL          | NULL           |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| some_other_key       | Y                      | NULL          | NULL           |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
```

To deal with this, we need do add case statements to our ORDER BY, so that the meta_value column would be used only to order posts that actually have `tdlrm_mp_1494` meta key in it.

We can achieve this by setting up an orderby filter.

**This is how:**

Here are our meta query arguments. Note the `orderby` argument set to false (we do not need it).

```
$taxonomy = 1494; // for demonstration purposes
$args['meta_query'] = array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        'mp_exists' => array(
            'key' => 'tdlrm_mp_'.$taxonomy,
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
        ),
        'mp_not_exists' => array(
            'key' => 'tdlrm_mp_'.$taxonomy,
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        )
    );
$args['orderby'] = false;
```

First, we add a custom variable to our query arguments, to let WP know where to use the filter:

```
$args['tdlrm_commands'] = array(
        'filter' => 'orderby_filter_1',
        'key' => 'tdlrm_mp_'.$taxonomy
    );
```

Second, we add the filter (to functions.php or a plugin file, whatever):

```
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', function ( $orderby, $query ) {

    //won't fire for other queries
    if(
    empty($query->query['tdlrm_commands']['do'])
    || $query->query['tdlrm_commands']['do'] !== 'orderby_filter_1'
    )
    {
    return $orderby;
    }

    global $wpdb;

    $meta_clauses = $query->meta_query->get_clauses();
    
    //get the key we passed in our custom argument
    $key = $query->query['tdlrm_commands']['key'];

    //get the table alias (remember there are multiple postmeta tables joined together,
    //we need only the one that satisfies our meta query clause, `mp_exists`)
    $has_tdlrm_mp = $meta_clauses['mp_exists']['alias'];


    /*
    in the postmeta table with alias {$has_tdlrm_mp},
    when meta_key equals to {$key},
    use the first clause,
    otherwise, use the second.

    first clause:
    in the postmeta table with alias {$has_tdlrm_mp},
    when meta_key equals to {$key},
    order by its meta value, in the ascending order
    (+0 casts a string to number, otherwise 21 will go after 2 and before 3.)

    second clause:
    if it's not, order by title, in the ascending order
    */
    $orderby = " CASE {$has_tdlrm_mp}.meta_key
                    WHEN '{$key}' THEN 1
                    ELSE 2
                END ASC,
                CASE {$has_tdlrm_mp}.meta_key
                    WHEN '{$key}' THEN {$has_tdlrm_mp}.meta_value+0
                END ASC,
                {$wpdb->posts}.post_title ASC";

    return $orderby;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have multiple meta values so your order by should be more targeted, like this.

```php
$args['orderby'] = array(
    'mp_exists'     => 'ASC',
    'mp_not_exists' => 'ASC',
    'title'         => 'ASC'
);
```

I don't know by what meta you want to order so I added both of them, remove as necessary.

Comment: Both variants produce identical order of posts (tested directly via MySQL in PHPMyAdmin, to exclude any filters)