# Custom Wp_query loop takes very long

Tags: wp-query, loop

I've got a simple custom WP_Query on a custom post type page that shows a collection of posts:

```
$t_query = new WP_Query($filters['filtered_args_for_query']);
```

`$wpdb->last_query` outputs:

```
SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (203046,205067,205540,206297,207374,207391,207996,209090,210979,211141,211153,211166) ORDER BY meta_id ASC
```

Whenever I place a simple Loop into my template, it takes 9 seconds to process the page (otherwise, 1 second):

```
if($t_query->have_posts()){
   while($t_query->have_posts()){
      $t_query->the_post();
   }
}
```

There are some 60 000 posts and 250 000 meta entries in my database. BUT, on other pages (category pages), that have the same custom query, my server serves pages in just a second or so. There, `$wpdb->last_query` returns:

```
SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (187887,189775,189853,190680,192412,196893,215373) ORDER BY meta_id ASC
```

To me, they both seem pretty much alike.

Can someone tell me what makes such a difference, or where to search? There must be something in the Loop that makes the difference, since the pages for the custom post type and the category load just the same when I remove the Loop, and since (for debug purposes) my Loop doesn't do anything except preparing posts.

Edit.
An example of `$filters['filtered_args_for_query']` is:

```
  ["post_type"]=>
  string(16) "tdlrm_store_item"
  ["post__in"]=>
  array(42) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "203046"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "203514"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "205034"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "205067"
    [4]=>
    string(6) "205286"
    [5]=>
    string(6) "205321"
    [6]=>
    string(6) "205540"
    [7]=>
    string(6) "205596"
    [8]=>
    string(6) "205616"
    [9]=>
    string(6) "205637"
    [10]=>
    string(6) "206297"
    [11]=>
    string(6) "206325"
    [12]=>
    string(6) "206887"
    [13]=>
    string(6) "207229"
    [14]=>
    string(6) "207232"
    [15]=>
    string(6) "207253"
    [16]=>
    string(6) "207322"
    [17]=>
    string(6) "207374"
    [18]=>
    string(6) "207391"
    [19]=>
    string(6) "207828"
    [20]=>
    string(6) "207996"
    [21]=>
    string(6) "208015"
    [22]=>
    string(6) "208027"
    [23]=>
    string(6) "208178"
    [24]=>
    string(6) "208186"
    [25]=>
    string(6) "208300"
    [26]=>
    string(6) "208306"
    [27]=>
    string(6) "208410"
    [28]=>
    string(6) "209244"
    [29]=>
    string(6) "210979"
    [30]=>
    string(6) "210991"
    [31]=>
    string(6) "211093"
    [32]=>
    string(6) "211141"
    [33]=>
    string(6) "211150"
    [34]=>
    string(6) "211153"
    [35]=>
    string(6) "211157"
    [36]=>
    string(6) "211165"
    [37]=>
    string(6) "211166"
    [38]=>
    string(6) "211521"
    [39]=>
    string(6) "217942"
    [40]=>
    string(6) "225640"
    [41]=>
    string(6) "209090"
  }
  ["posts_per_page"]=>
  int(12)
  ["paged"]=>
  int(1)
  ["tdlrm_commands"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["do"]=>
    string(16) "orderby_filter_1"
    ["key"]=>
    string(9) "tdlrm_mp_"
  }
  ["meta_query"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["relation"]=>
    string(2) "OR"
    ["mp_exists"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["key"]=>
      string(9) "tdlrm_mp_"
      ["type"]=>


      string(7) "NUMERIC"
        }
        ["mp_not_exists"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["key"]=>
          string(9) "tdlrm_mp_"
          ["compare"]=>
          string(10) "NOT EXISTS"
        }
      }
      ["orderby"]=>
      bool(false)
    }
```

Comment: What is `$filters['filtered_args_for_query']`?

Comment: Hey Jacob. It's just some WP_Query arguments that depend on my current needs, including some custom commands to filter the MySQL query. I've added an example to my question. On a taxonomy page they would not have the `post__in` argument, but include a `tax_query` instead.

Comment: Well the arguments are what's important, because that's what would be making the query slow. Your example seems like a fairly complex query. What is `tdlrm_commands`?

Comment: Jacob, probably this is best explained in my other question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/396024/whats-wrong-with-this-meta-query-order-by-meta-key-then-title-doesnt-work.

You see, the resulting raw MySQL query is very simple and takes only 0.0011 in PHPMyAdmin. It is the iteration over the results that is slow.

Comment: Wait. What if I use $wpdb->last query in the loop...

Comment: Yeah. I did use $wpdb->last_query  inside the loop and found out there is a hook that updates an insane amount of meta every time a post is processed.

Comment: Thank you for your help though, Jacob.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my question. I used the following code:

```
global $wpdb;
if($t_query->have_posts()){
   while($t_query->have_posts()){
      $t_query->the_post();
      echo $wpdb->last_query."\r\n";
   }
}
```

and it showed there was an action somewhere hooked to `the_post` hook, sending requests to update some meta every time a post was processed.

So, the answer to my question is: I should have used `$wpdb->last_query` inside the loop to find out what was going on.